# CodeIgniter Validation Callback not being Called

Tags: validation, codeigniter

My callback function from validation rules isn’t being called.
  The other validation rules for that field ARE being called

```
$rules[‘login_name’] = “required|max_length[12]|alpha_dash|callback__check_login_name”;
function _check_login_name($login_name) {
    echo "here"; // DOESNT WORK
 }
```

So in the above line, required, max_length, alpha_dash are being called, but the callback isn't.
Thanks!

Comment: What about die('here'); instead? Could be that the echo is being called but you're just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the method is somehow not readable out of scope.  Does it work when you simply call _check_login_name manually (from outside of the class)?  If that is not the issue, then have you tried placing echo's in the system folder's Form_validation.php?  Place a series in after line 581.  After that, more code will be needed in order to give more help.

Comment: CI form_validation() callbacks don't get called when in libraries, they must be in a controller.

Comment: @stef CYS. CI does not use debug_backtrace to restrict where and how code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try this instead of the echo:

```
function _check_login_name($login_name) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_login_name', 'The callback was called.');
    return FALSE;
}
```

Per the [callbacks entry in the CI manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks):
"If your callback returns anything other than a boolean TRUE/FALSE it is assumed that the data is your newly processed form data."

Comment: The value of the return should not have anything to do with whether the echo is working, unless he is somehow calling that inside of the view...

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you're using the [old validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html). Try the new [Form Validation Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html). I think there was a bug with that in the old one.

Comment: that might be it; will check it out